# Extended latin characters missing on save() - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, encoding

Long story short - whenever I'm trying to save string containing extended Latin characters (in my case Latvian), for example:

```
Lorem Ipsum ir kļuvis par vispārpieņemtu teksta aizvietotāju kopš 16. gadsimta sākuma.
```

on `save()` it saves the string in database without special characters, like so:

```
Lorem Ipsum ir kuvis par visprpieemtu teksta aizvietotju kop 16. gadsimta skuma.
```

I double checked my database default charset and it is `utf8mb4` with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation. The file containing the controller that saves to database is `UTF-8`. Also I double checked string before saving it to database - it returns full Latvian string.

Before trying PHP `Normalizer` class, I would like to ask for some insight from you guys. what am I doing wrong? What could be causing this?

Also I have a feeling that on other non-Latin charsets (extended Cyrillic for example) it will fail to save the extended characters too (haven't it tested tho').

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Please debug it by providing `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some short string that has lost letters.  `ļ` should show hex `C4BC`; `ņ` -> `C586`, etc.

Comment: I doubt if you need Normalizer for anything.

Comment: @RickJames debugging chars, doesn't give me anything in this situation. It's the way it's been saved to database. And I can't put my head around it, as before `save()` the string is allright, but exactly after it being pushed to database, the chars are gone. Also `Normalizer` is the last option in this scenario, as it will replace the special characters and replace them with Latin.

Comment: How are you entering the Latvian characters?  A special keyboard?  Combining characters?  ALT+123?  Copying from some other source?  Other?

Comment: There's no issue with keyboard, character encoding before save. It's something to do how Laravel parses the characters. I've been developing in latvian a lot of projects and this is first time encountering such issue. As I said above - the latvian characters are showing in `dump` before `save()`